# Javascript locale string in OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, localization, locale, date-format

I'm trying to determine the user locale date format via JavaScript but can't for the life of me get any browser to actually change the output of `date.toLocaleDateString()` to a different format than where I actually am (US).

I've tried setting `System Preferences - Language & Text - Formats - Region = UK`, setting the system language to french, but I still get US formatted dates.

Any ideas?

Alternatively, can anyone tell me what this jsfiddle gives them in a different locale?  http://jsfiddle.net/N6VxW/

I get `[Friday, ]August 26, 2011` or `08/26/2011` depending on the browser

Comment: I get "26. aug 2011" in Safari, which is correct for my Mac's locale (Denmark). So even though my OS is in English, it respects my date format settings as it should. Chrome, however, does not. It gives me "Friday, August 26, 2011" which is obviously in English

Comment: FYI: Firefox gives me "08/26/2011" which is wrong for Denmark (we use DD/MM/YYYY), and Opera gives me "Friday August 26, 2011" (note: No comma after "Friday"). So no matter what, `toLocaleDateString()` seems to be terribly, terribly inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that...  Thanks though for testing this :)  I just noticed that Safari is giving me the correct result when I change my locale, however, so thanks for pointing that out.  I was noticing that neither FF nor Chrome seemed to pay attention, so I thought the setting wasn't taking effect somehow...  Stupid browsers!  I just want to know what format to put a date in!  :(

Comment: I can't say I'm suprised that Safari is the only browser that's paying attention to this stuff, although I expected Opera to do so too (Norwegians, I am dissappoint!). In any case, you're probably better off making it a user preference, or sussing out the user's locale some other way and formatting the date accordingly… but it's a bummer that it doesn't "just work" like it should. I mean, 4 different browser literally gave me 4 different answers, and only one of them was actually correct

Comment: I do completely agree with you: we cannot rely on 'toLocaleDateString()` !!! Also using locales ([see this link]) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FtoLocaleDateString) it's not running on Safari !!! :(

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. On Chrome Mac OS X it results with `8/26/2011`, on Chrome Windows it results with `26/8/2011`. I'm in the UK with UK region settings on both machines.